# IBM MQ client preventing garbage into the console output

Tags: java, spring-boot, ibm-mq

we are using IBM MQ client (com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.1.3.0.jar) from a Spring-Boot project sending mq messages, the problem is the too many (tons) garbage output into the console:

```
..... ----+----+-  }  <init>(JmqiEnvironment)
..... ----+----+-  {  setUserDataSingle(byte [ ],int) <null> [0(0x0)]
..... ----+----+-  }  setUserDataSingle(byte [ ],int)
```

(xxx are replacement for privacy)

How can we control/remove the this low level info from the console ?
Thanks in advance,

Csaba

Comment: I looks like you have trace enabled.  See if you have the java system property `com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.trace.status=ON` set.

Comment: JoshMc many thanks you are right, its set. We try it in the next deployment, you helped lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I looks like you have trace enabled.

Check if you have the java system property `com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.trace.status=ON` set.  If it is set,  remove it and restart.